# Подмена сайта в WIndows 10

Tags: windows, веб-сервер

Нужно чтобы при воде любого адреса в браузере, открывалась определенная страница, неважно где она будет на той-же машине или на другом адресе.

Как это сделать?
(Win 10)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Эээ `прокси сервер`?